# How do I alert XML file in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, soap

This is a login api in which I am trying to send an xml document but it is showing an error. After removing `<?` this, it is not showing error but I need to send with it. Can anyone help me to send the whole xml with any other type or method?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var xmldata='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelopexmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><username>ddd@c.in</username><password>Year#2018@2018</password></login></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';
        alert(xmldata);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url',
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {
               'Content-Type': "text/xml",
               'SOAPAction': "",
            } ,
            dataType: 'xml',
            contentType: "text/xml",
            data: {xml:xmldata},
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data, errorThrown) {
               console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also I am getting a cross domain error in this code. How can I send the SOAP data?

Comment: Please post your error. P.s. where do you define url in your ajax function?

Comment: Getting a cross domain error means you are not allowed to do this action as the receiving end blocks you. Is the backend service you are trying to call yours?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var xmldata='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelopexmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><username>ddd@c.in</username><password>Year#2018@2018</password></login></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';
alert(xmldata);
$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {          
       'Content-Type': "text/xml",
       'SOAPAction': "",
    } ,
    dataType: 'xml',
    contentType: "text/xml",
    data: {xml:xmldata},
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data, errorThrown) {
       console.log(data);
    }            
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add the jQuery library (which you can google or see the snippet) before the script runs.

I think your problem about not getting the whole XML content will be solved.

Comment: He is getting a cross domain error. Not "$ is not defined".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

In Internet Explorer:

```
xmlObject.xml
```

Other browsers:

```
(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlObject)
```